# Why do I get random symbols when editing a text file in C?

Tags: c

I'm currently trying to create a program in C which creates, edits and prints a .txt document. At the moment I'm pretty new to C, but I've managed to create like half of the whole code.

The whole concept is:

1. Write data to a .txt file in list order
2. Add data to currently existing one (at the end of the list)
3. Delete items which are listed as X place or higher (x entered by keyboard)
4. Show on screen the whole list

So far I've managed to do 1 and 4, and I'm having a strange issue with 2. When I open the text file, I see random symbols all over the place. Any idea whats causing that? Also any advice for the 3rd point will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct legumes
{
    int id;
    char name [35];
};
void Saisie (struct legumes b[20],int nbl);
void Affiche (struct legumes b[20],int nbl);
int main (){
    FILE *fpr ;
    FILE *fpw;
    struct legumes b [20];
    int i ;
    int nbl;
    char rep ;
    fpw =fopen("program.txt","w");
    fpr =fopen("program.txt","r");
    if (fpr== NULL || fpw == NULL){
        printf("\nError ");
        exit (1);
    }
    printf("Combien de legumes vous voule entre ?");
    scanf("%d",&nbl);
    do
    {
        puts("Saisie, Affiche, Moyenne, Quitter ?");
        printf("%c\n",rep=toupper(getch()));
        switch (rep)
        {
        case 'S':Saisie(b ,nbl);break;
        case 'A': Affiche (b , nbl);break;
        }
    }while (rep!='Q');
}
void Saisie (struct legumes b[20],int nbl){
    FILE *fpw;
    fpw =fopen("program.txt","w");
    int i ;
    printf("\nDonnez le donnes des legumes ");
    for (i=0;i<nbl ;i++){
        printf ("\nDonez le id de %d legume =",i+1);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d",&b[i].id );
        printf("\nDonez le nom de %d legume = ",i+1);
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(b[i].name);
    }

    fwrite (b,sizeof(struct legumes),nbl,fpw);
    fclose (fpw);
}
void Affiche (struct legumes b[20],int nbl){
    FILE *fpr ;
    int i ;
    fpr =fopen("program.txt","r");
    fread(b , sizeof(struct legumes),nbl,fpr);
    printf("\n Legumes :");
    for (i=0;i<nbl;i++){
        printf("\n legume %d id =%d ",i+1,b[i].id);
        printf("\ le nom %d est = %s",i+1,b[i].name);
    }
    fclose (fpr);
}
```

Comment: Please give sample output to demonstrate "random symbols all over the place". Please apply indentation to your code. Please translate everything to English. These things will increase your chances to find help.

Comment: You're writing binary data to the file, you shouldn't expect it to be readable in a text editor.

Comment: Why do you open the file in `main()`? You never use those file handles? Also, opening a file in `w` mode will empty the file, there's no point in opening it in `r` mode right after.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is not standard C. You should use `fgets()` to read whole lines.

Comment: Do not use `gets(b[i].name);`. `gets()` is a dangerous function that has been removed from the language. Use `fgets()`.

Comment: Yes, `fwrite()` writes the binary data to the file. If you want the file to be text, use `fprintf()`.